# PHP Include not recognized in html

Tags: php, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<?php include('head.php'); ?>
</head>
<body>
-snip-
</body>
</html>
```

What am I doing wrong? When I open this file (index.html) in a browser it shows a blank page, and nothing in my php file shows. It doesn't recognize the include statement as code.

My php file contains this:

```
<title>Title here</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
```

Feel free to yell at me, as I am a beginner. I tried looking this up and I made sure the syntax is correct.

Comment: you can use php only in files named `*.php` not `*.html`

Comment: Even after I renamed it to index.php it did not affect anything.

Comment: Do you got PHP installed? Like XAMPP or something?

Comment: you cannot open the file directly in the browser. Add the path to the php server (if u can understand what im saying)

Comment: No, doing so now. I think that's the issue.

Comment: do u open the page by typing some domain name like `localhost` in your browser?

Comment: @kevin You can run php in any file (when setting up the webserver to parse the files as php).

Answer (score 2):

Use index.php not index.html as it is a php function it will not work on html. And you have to run this page in a php server otherwise it will not give result.

Comment: Oh, I see, maybe the php server is the issue then.

Comment: If you are using window you can install wamp server it is easy to install easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

First of all your file needs to be in `.php` extension. 
Secondly if you are trying this in your local system, you need to set-up a local web server, 
for this you can use, [wamp](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) or [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html)

Once the local server is ready, you can put your files under the `www` folder of your local server set-up and view the file in browser by loading,

`http://localhost/index.php`

or

`127.0.0.1/index.php`

Answer (score 0):

You need to do 2 things:
1. change index.html to index.php (otherwise the PHP server doesn't process your files)
2. change head.php to
    echo 'Title here';
    echo '';

Answer (score 0):

As you have XAMPP installed you need to be going to http://localhost to run your PHP scripts. Loading your PHP scripts directly into the web browser will not work.